# How to configure FS database in playframework 2.0?

Tags: database, playframework-2.0, filesystems, h2

is it possible at all? Seems easy to be done in the first version of the framework.

Comment: it uses simple files to store, @Somatik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using

```
# Default database configuration
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

you should be able to just use

```
# FS database configuration
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:playdb"
```

This will create the file in the current working directory. See the [H2 CheatSheet](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html) for more information