# How do you configure a File System with Play Framework 2.0 while keeping my current MySQL database?

Tags: playframework, filesystems, blob, playframework-2.0, filepath

So I'm trying to figure out how I can configure a filesystem with Play Framework 2.0 to store blob type files, while using a database to store it's directory/path to reference.

Having some trouble doing this, but I've found a link that shows you how to configure it as a main alternative, but it is in place of a database.

I'm trying to use the database to store the reference path in the file system so that I could reference that back to the actual location of the blob file or image stored. Has anyone done this before? If so, help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

<s>Here is the link: [How to configure FS database in playframework 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150287/how-to-configure-fs-database-in-playframework-2-0)</s>

(*editor's note: this link is useless for this question, as it's describes configuring H2 storage configuration*)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up things a little, the link you provided instructs how to configure whole `H2` database to be storred on the disk or just in the memory.

For your purpose you should just adopt [File Upload sample from Play's documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaFileUpload)

The additional thing you have to do BEFORE `return ok("File uploaded");` line is to find record in your MySQL and update it by adding `fileName`  and/or `contentType` as a refference to file storred on the disk.

Play for a while with `File` type, then you'll be able to store files in FS where you'll want and how you'll want

Comment: Thank you, I apologize in advance for the late response this helps!